# Mid line between gluing bead?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I need to create a code in matlab that automatically finds the centerline in a glue bead. I've seen some solutions to a similar problem, but since the glue bead is closed (like a ring), it's much more difficult for me.

I just figured I'd take the outer contour of the ring and let it gradually approach the inner contour. Until the distance between the inner and outer contour is zero, but that didn't work.

Is there any other way to do this?
Thanks for your answers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZZ82.png)